# Plot mean and contour of 2D Gaussian

Tags: r, plot, statistics

Suppose I have a Gaussian with a certain mean and variance-covariance matrix

```
mu <- c(1, 2)
Sigma <- matrix(c(2, 0.5, 
                  0.5, 1), nrow=2)
```

I would like to plot a point for the mean (at (1, 2)) and around it I would like to plot an ellipse corresponding to one standard deviation. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `ellipse` package is just one of several packages that have functions for drawing ellipses. Install the package and then load it. You have to compute the probability level for the number of standard deviations since the function does not accept standard deviations directly:

```
library(ellipse)
plot(mu[1], mu[2], xlim=c(-2, 4), ylim=c(0, 4))
lvl <- diff(pnorm(c(-1, 1)))
lines(ellipse(Sigma, scale=c(1.4, 1), centre=c(1, 2), level=lvl))
```

[image: Ellipse]

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you mind explaining me what you mean by level? What are you using `diff(norm())` for?

Comment: Also how did you get `c(1.4, 1)`?

Comment: If I compute the correlation matrix from `Sigma` using `cov2cor(Sigma)` I get 

`1.0000000 0.3535534
0.3535534 1.0000000`

Comment: The `level=` argument is the confidence level, the area under the normal curve between +/- 1 standard deviation in your case. The `pnorm` function gives you the area under the curve from the left side of the curve so we have to subtract the area from -Inf to -1 sd from the area from -Inf to +1 sd. The variances of your variables are 2 and 1 so the standard deviations are sqrt(2) and sqrt(1).